# How to find the minimal polynomial if I know its minimal polynomial in a subfield.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, roots, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

> If $\omega$ is the cube root of unity then I know it’s minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2 + x +1$. How do I know this is still the minimal polynomial of $\omega$ over $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/3})$?

I know the only roots of $x^2+x+1$ are $\omega$ and $\omega ^2$. And so I thought this still wouldn’t split in $\mathbb{Q}(7^{1/3})$ and therefore must still be irreducible in the larger field.

But does this logic work in general? If a polynomial is irreducible over a field and none of its roots are in the field extension does that mean it is still irreducible in the field extension?

Comment: Also is cube root of unity the same thing as primitive cube root of unity?

Comment: No, that needs to be specified. The cube roots of $1$ are $1,\omega,\omega^2$.

Comment: $1$ is also a cube root of $1$, but not a [*primitive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#General_definition) cube root of $1$

Comment: What is primitive cube root of one?

Comment: $\omega ^1$????

Comment: If $n$ is a positive integer, we say$\;x\in\mathbb{C}\;$is a _primitive_ $n$-th root of unity if $x^n=1$, and $x^m\ne 1$ for any positive integer $m < n$.$\;$So if $w=exp(2i\pi/3)$, then $w$ and $w^2$ are both primitive cube roots of $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple counterexample, let $f(x)=x^4-2$.

Then $f$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, but over the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, $f$ factors as $(x^2+\sqrt{2})(x^2-\sqrt{2})$.

However none of the roots of $x^4-2$ are elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$.

Comment: So why did my argument work the first time?

Comment: Because if a a polynomial of degree $2$ or $3$ factors over a field, then it must have a linear factor, hence must have a root in the field. Moreover if a quadratic polynomial factors over a field, then the field must contain both roots.

Comment: Thank you very much.